# How to install Repo Tool

Tags: repository, git

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed the instructions [here](https://source.android.com/source/downloading)

Specifically:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo

chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

However, after doing so a html file is downloaded. There does not appear to be an executable file. If I then run repo init, it gives the following error:

"The program 'repo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing apt-get install phablet-tools"

Now typing this will of course work. The problem is, I cannot use the phablet-tools packaged version of repo, as it is not approved. So how **exactly** do I get repo installed?

Here are the first few lines of the file that is downloaded:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# repo default configuration
#
import os
REPO_URL = os.environ.get('REPO_URL', None)
if not REPO_URL:
  REPO_URL = 'https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo'
REPO_REV = 'stable'
```

If I try to open the file in a browser I get a 404 "the requested ULR /fit-repo was not found on this server."

Here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/2Bbu9mQZ) to the complete file as downloaded.

Comment: html files you open in your browser. maybe it shows you a webpage with info?

Comment: Can you **[edit]** as complete as possible a description of everything you have tried, and everything that's happened so far, into your question? Some more information would also be helpful. Run `cd; wget https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo` to download the file, in a slightly different way, to your home directory. Then run `cmp ~/bin/repo repo` to check for any difference. If it shows output then they are different (or there was an error). If it shows no output then they are the same. Please also run `sha256sum repo ~/bin/repo`, and put all this in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The program was downloaded correctly (At least from the parts you pasted here it seems to be the valid repo python script). You probably need to add the ~/bin directory to your PATH variable to make it work.

To do this, you need to run the following command in your Terminal:
`export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"`

Check now if the `repo` command works.

If it works, to make those changes persistent, simply add this command from above to the end of your .bashrc file.

Comment: After running that command, I still get the 'repo' is currently not installed, error.

Comment: Oops, sorry I made a typo (I accidentally wrote ~/.bin instead of ~/bin (Because I always name the folder .bin). I fixed it in my answer. Please try again

Comment: Ok, that did something. So now the error is," line 1: syntax errors near unexpected token 'newline'  <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Could you please paste the complete file (pastebin, etc.) that was downloaded into ~/bin/repo? Because in the Question you sent you pasted a snippet of the file like it should be, not as it was downloaded to your PC. Also, I don't see any error in the commands you pasted, they work totally fine for me. Are you typing thise commands into Terminal manually or are you copy-pasting them there? Please make sure you haven't made any typos.

Comment: I added a link to the pastebin in the original question. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is either not the output of the file as it was downloaded (Because it clearly reports a DOCTYPE in the first line of something, but it isn't there in the file you posted), or I have been missing something about the error message. Could you pastebin the whole error message you get when running `repo`?

Comment: @TimSchumacher There's probably no need to add `export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"` to any bash config files. With [the default configuration for user accounts created in a 14.04 system](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/bash/trusty-security/view/head:/debian/skel.profile), `bin` in the user's home dir is added to `$PATH` on login if it exists. Logging out and in is enough (before that, the `export` command you gave can be used). `.bashrc` isn't a great place to prepend variables; it will tack multiple `~/bin`s on the front of `$PATH` when one shell is a subprocess of another.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan Previously it reported that the command wasn't found and after adding it to the PATH manually solved the problem (now it at least tries to run it). The same directory being in the PATH variable shouldn't be a problem either, if it even occurs.

Comment: @TimSchumacher It's quite confusing, though, when people look at their `PATH` variables. There are other reasons to avoid setting it in `.bashrc`. For example, even if the user only ever uses bash themselves when they want a shell, if a program that was not run from a bash shell (for example, because it was launched from the desktop) needs to call `repo`, this will fail, since `.bashrc` is bash-specific and is unlikely to be sourced otherwise. Of course, if it is *also* being set in `.profile`, then that particular limitation of `.bashrc` is not a problem.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan That is indeed true (that there could be problems when using Programs that depend on repo), but honestly I don't know of any programs that use repo without directly including the executable inside their program

Comment: So any idea where I've gone wrong here?

Comment: @Rick No I haven't, but if you can't get repo to work at all, you can also just remove the ~/bin/repo file, remove the new added line from .bashrc and install the `phablet-tools` package via apt, which ships an older but confirmed to be running version of `repo`

Comment: Yeah, it did that, but had to remove it as it was not approved.

Comment: @Rick Are you getting the *same* "not installed" error as before, or a different one? Before you got `The program 'repo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing apt-get install phablet-tools`. Has this changed to `error: repo is not installed.  Use "repo init" to install it here.`? If so, *that's normal*, and you can follow those instructions. (You'll need git.) *Tim Schumacher:* I'm more worried about other programs being added to `~/bin` in the future, seeming to be in the search path, but sometimes not being used. But assuming `.profile` already adds it, there's no problem.

Comment: No, now the error is line 1 syntax error as I mentioned previously.

Comment: @Rick could you please run the commands `which repo` and `cat "$(which repo)"`, pastebin the output of both seperately and send the links here ?